# How to add space in python 2 in print method

Tags: python

In python I am printing using nested loops like this:

```
for i in range(3): 
    for j in range(3): 
        print(j, end = " ") 
    print()
```

This is working with python 3, but how to use the `end` attribute in python 2:

```
for i in range(3): 
    for j in range(3): 
        print j, end = " "
    print
```

If I use this code, I am getting invalid syntax error

Comment: why not just print j, " "?

Comment: @MWaz, because they will get new line, after the space and that's what they wnt to avoid :-)

Comment: Use `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 2, the syntax for what you are trying to do is simply

```
print j,
```

This acts the same as

```
print(j, end = " ")
```

In python 3